# How to run MSUnit tests with MSBuild

Tags: msbuild, mstest

I have a MSBuild script which looks similar to:

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <Target Name="Build">

        <MSBuild Projects="MyProject.UnitTest.sln" Targets="Build" />

    </Target>
</Project>
```

How do I run the MSTest unit tests which are within the solution?

I am looking for something similar to what can be used in TFS Build of:

```
<TestContainerInOutput Include="%2a%2a\%2aTest.dll" />
```